# Phrase to express frustration towards the weather

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a short story set in England and looking for a proper word or phrase that can be uttered by the primary character (an old man) to show his frustration on the sudden rain.  In the scene, it starts drizzling just as he walks out of a coffee shop. I'm looking for a suitable response right here to express his frustration on the situation. Something like..."Damn it!", but in a British way. What would an Englishman say in such circumstance.

The character is so far a fairly unlikable man who is always irritated and hates just about everything.

Comment: This may be better suited to the ELU (English Language Usage) stack -- they have a common tag called "single word for..."  You can specify you want a UK/English specific answer, too.

Comment: British native here! You may also wish to specify era and region - an "old man" in the 21st century will use very different words/phrases for this than one in say the 1940s. Region possibly plays even more of a role, North West vs North East vs South East would all likely use very different words in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I think this question might be closed for being a "what to write" type of question, but I'll give you some pointers.

I'm not fluent in old-man British, and, of course, every person has their own unique language.

He COULD use phrases like "Bollocks!" or "Blimey!", BUT, I suggest looking up "Classic British curse words / vulgar slang" online.

Hope it helps!